# Crontab mysqldump has massive error log

Tags: mysql, cron

I am scheduling a backup (with error logging) of a mysql database, using the following command in crontab:

```
0 4 * * * mysqldump -u root -p PASS database > backup_`date "+\%F"`.sql 2> cron_back.log
```

I could wrap the msqldump command in bash script, which is then scheduled in crontab, but I'd like to do it in a more straight forward way if possible, and understand what I'm doing wrong wth my error logging.

The issue is this that the log file appears to be the actual mysqldump, as show below.

```
$ls -l

-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 27091521 Nov  1 04:00 cron_back.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 27959895 Nov  1 04:00 backup_2017-11-01.sql
```

Looking a bit deeper:

```
$nano cron_back.log                                                                                        

-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: database
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `AreaLayoutColumns`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `AreaLayoutColumns`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `AreaLayoutColumns` (
  `arLayoutColumnID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

and finally ending, after many pages, with ...

```
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `gaPage` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-10-31  4:00:04
```

I'd prefer that the log file contains only error messages.

Comment: You should use --log-error=file_name rather than assuming that errors will end up on fd 2. Also there can be *no space* between 2>logfile the way you have it in the crontab.  All of this can be found by simply looking at the documentation.

Comment: Based on the *backup_`date "+\%H"`.sql*, the output file would have been named `backup_<hour>.sql` and not `backup_2017-11-01.sql`. `%H` is hour tag. How come your output file has full date in it. Have you mentioned incorrect date format mentioned in the question?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. 

Ahmed, thanks for your answer, I'll look into that and likely implement.

Sorry for the confusion, Madhurkar. I had the same issue on two jobs, and inadvertently crossed the command with the output.

Comment: Madhukar, I have update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the space between 2> and file

```
0 * * * * mysqldump -u root -p PASS database > backup_`date "+\%H"`.sql 2>cron_back.log
```